# SQL - select the most frequency item

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the table as below:

```
id | name
----------
01 | Tony
02 | Peter
03 | Tony
04 | Tony
05 | John
.. | ..
99 | David
```

How can I use SQL statement to get the most frequency of the field name(Tony)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT name
FROM table_name
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the Mode. This article explains how to get it (look at the last code example):

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/calculating-mean-median-and-mode-with-sq

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*)  
FROM YourNames 
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 1
```